# Redux Chain Multiple Ajax Promises in one Action

Tags: redux, react-redux, superagent

I have a Redux action which needs to make 2 subsequent ajax calls.

The first calls googlemaps api: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${searchTerm}&key=${gmapsKey}`

The second calls a local service based on those results
`/api/content/stores/byDistance/${lat},${lng}/sort`

I'm using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to do the ajax calls. Clearly I'm experience difficulties keeping track of the promises, and including failures.

Am I mis-undestanding a core concept of Promises? Is there a simpler way to write the below?

```
export function loadBySearch(searchTerm) {

    const geoSearchUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${searchTerm}&key=${gmapsKey}`;

    return {
        types: [LOAD, LOAD_BY_LAT_LONG, LOAD_FAIL],
        //Do I need to make this promise here?
        promise: (client) => {
            const promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
                console.info('making google geocode request', geoSearchUrl);
                superagent.get(geoSearchUrl)
                    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                    .then( (successData1) =>{
                        const results = successData1.body.results;
                        if (!results.length) {
                            reject(`no results found for this search : ${searchTerm}`);
                            return;
                        }
                        const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                        const path = `/api/content/stores/byDistance/${lat},${lng}/sort`;
                        client.get(path).then(
                            (successData2) => {
                                resolve( {
                                    searchTerm: searchTerm,
                                    searchLocation: {
                                        lat,
                                        lng
                                    },
                                    data: successData2
                                });
                            },
                            (errorData2) => {
                                reject( {
                                    searchTerm: searchTerm,
                                    result: errorData2
                                });
                            },
                        );
                    },
                        (errorData1) => {
                            reject({
                                searchTerm: searchTerm,
                                result: errorData1
                            });
                        }
                );

            });

            return promise;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Might I recommend breaking this logic out functionally so it is much more clean and clear (in my opinion). And to answer your question, yes you need a promise there, and you just want to resolve the outer promise when all of your logic is done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using superagent, but I'm guessing something like this might just work:

```
superagent.get(geoSearchUrl)
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .then(successData1 => {
    const results = successData1.body.results;
    if (!results.length) {
      throw(`no results found for this search : ${searchTerm}`);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(results);
  })
  .then(results => {
    const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    const path = `/api/content/stores/byDistance/${lat},${lng}/sort`;
    return client.get(path);
  })
  .then(successData2 => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      searchTerm: searchTerm,
      searchLocation: {
        lat,
        lng
      },
      data: successData2
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return Promise.reject({
      searchTerm: searchTerm,
      result: error
    });
  });
```

Haven't test it, but I hope at least it helps ;)